Google Calendar API: Requesting only existing events
I'm hoping someone can pint me in the right direction. I am succesfully pulling events, calendars, multiple calendars, etc, uding the Google Calendar API. However, the results are showing each and every day of any month regardless if there is an actual event or not.
What field do I need to verify to weed out the "non events days" or what query do I need to filter the results?
Here is the current PHP array of the query options I'm using:
$optParams = array(
'maxResults' => 100,
'orderBy' => 'startTime',
'singleEvents' => TRUE,
//'timeMin' => date('c'),
'timeMin' => date('c', strtotime('-30 days'))
);

Thanks in advance!
Here is an example of an "empty" event:
Google\Service\Calendar\Event Object
(
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [collection_key:protected] => recurrence
    [anyoneCanAddSelf] => 
    [attachmentsType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventAttachment
    [attachmentsDataType:protected] => array
    [attendeesType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventAttendee
    [attendeesDataType:protected] => array
    [attendeesOmitted] => 
    [colorId] => 
    [conferenceDataType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\ConferenceData
    [conferenceDataDataType:protected] => 
    [created] => 2022-04-29T17:19:37.000Z
    [creatorType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventCreator
    [creatorDataType:protected] => 
    [description] => 
    [endType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventDateTime
    [endDataType:protected] => 
    [endTimeUnspecified] => 
    [etag] => "3412060797546000"
    [eventType] => workingLocation
    [extendedPropertiesType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventExtendedProperties
    [extendedPropertiesDataType:protected] => 
    [focusTimePropertiesType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventFocusTimeProperties
    [focusTimePropertiesDataType:protected] => 
    [gadgetType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventGadget
    [gadgetDataType:protected] => 
    [guestsCanInviteOthers] => 
    [guestsCanModify] => 
    [guestsCanSeeOtherGuests] => 
    [hangoutLink] => 
    [htmlLink] => https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=Ym0wdGdvMzNiZnV1MnRiZzc3aDg4OTJyaGNfMjAyNDA5MTYgZ3JlZ2dAYmx1bW9vY3JlYXRpdmUuY29t
    [iCalUID] => bm0tgo33bfuu2tbg77h8892rhc@google.com
    [id] => bm0tgo33bfuu2tbg77h8892rhc_20240916
    [kind] => calendar#event
    [location] => 
    [locked] => 
    [organizerType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventOrganizer
    [organizerDataType:protected] => 
    [originalStartTimeType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventDateTime
    [originalStartTimeDataType:protected] => 
    [outOfOfficePropertiesType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventOutOfOfficeProperties
    [outOfOfficePropertiesDataType:protected] => 
    [privateCopy] => 
    [recurrence] => 
    [recurringEventId] => bm0tgo33bfuu2tbg77h8892rhc
    [remindersType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventReminders
    [remindersDataType:protected] => 
    [sequence] => 0
    [sourceType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventSource
    [sourceDataType:protected] => 
    [startType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventDateTime
    [startDataType:protected] => 
    [status] => confirmed
    [summary] => Office
    [transparency] => transparent
    [updated] => 2024-01-23T17:19:58.773Z
    [visibility] => public
    [workingLocationPropertiesType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventWorkingLocationProperties
    [workingLocationPropertiesDataType:protected] => 
    [creator] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventCreator Object
        (
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [displayName] => Gregg Moore
            [email] => myemail@myemail.com
            [id] => 
            [self] => 1
        )

    [organizer] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventOrganizer Object
        (
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [displayName] => Gregg Moore
            [email] => myemail@myemail.com
            [id] => 
            [self] => 1
        )

    [start] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventDateTime Object
        (
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [date] => 2024-09-16
            [dateTime] => 
            [timeZone] => 
        )

    [end] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventDateTime Object
        (
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [date] => 2024-09-17
            [dateTime] => 
            [timeZone] => 
        )

    [originalStartTime] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventDateTime Object
        (
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [date] => 2024-09-16
            [dateTime] => 
            [timeZone] => 
        )

    [reminders] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventReminders Object
        (
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [collection_key:protected] => overrides
            [overridesType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventReminder
            [overridesDataType:protected] => array
            [useDefault] => 
        )

    [workingLocationProperties] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventWorkingLocationProperties Object
        (
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [customLocationType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventWorkingLocationPropertiesCustomLocation
            [customLocationDataType:protected] => 
            [homeOffice] => 
            [officeLocationType:protected] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventWorkingLocationPropertiesOfficeLocation
            [officeLocationDataType:protected] => 
            [type] => officeLocation
            [officeLocation] => Google\Service\Calendar\EventWorkingLocationPropertiesOfficeLocation Object
                (
                    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [modelData:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [processed:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [buildingId] => 
                    [deskId] => 
                    [floorId] => 
                    [floorSectionId] => 
                    [label] => 
                )

        )

)


Why do you need to filter them out in the API? Just ignore those days when processing the results.

@barmar  thanks for the comment.  Initially, I was thinking the same, but from what I can see in the results, there is no accurate way to "ignore" them while processing the results. Maybe I'm missing something.

Just use an if statement when looping over the results to ignore days with no events.

I agree, if it was that simple. Again, I don’t see any field that I can call against. It’s frustrating for sure.

I can't see this making sense. The API documentation doesn't say anything about it returning "all dates" within the given time frame, it is supposed to return actual events. Are you really sure you don't have an actual event here? One that might perhaps "look" different than others, have different properties ...? I mean, it gives you a link to the event, it says its status was confirmed, it has created and updated timestamps at "irregular" times ... all of which makes it look like an actual event to me.

Why do you consider this event record to be "empty"? Just because it has no description, do you mean? It's certainly an event, at any rate. In my experience the calendar API doesn't return event records just to mark a day. Have you checked in the google calendar UI for the target calendar, to see what it actually looks like in there? Maybe someone created an event (maybe even a recurring event) with no description or something.

And if you do want to ignore events like this, just do if (empty($event->description)) { continue; } to skip it.

@Barmar Again, thanks for your feedback. I'm still trying to figure out why the API doesn't just return actual events. I named the non-events "empty" for a better understanding.  The issue with using description as the field to ignore is that it could be empty for an actual event. Also, the events along with non-events produced date or timestamps... that doesn't make sense to me as well. The only field I figured that I could actually use is the "recurringEventId". If it's NOT empty, it means it's not an event, at least it's not a "ONE-OFF" event. The issue, of course... cont

then you're screwed. But, you did mention something that the API should only be returning actual events, so I'm going to create another calendar and see what happens!  Thank you!

why the API doesn't just return actual events...it does. You are mistaken. If you ask it for events it doesn't return anything which isn't an event. So far you've provided no evidence which proves otherwise. There is no [mre] of your issue in the question, and therefore no problem to solve. The calendar you're talking to contains that event data, and the API is returning it to you, exactly as you requested it to.

the "recurringEventId". If it's NOT empty, it means it's not an event...no, it just means it's a recurring event. That's still an event. If you want to ignore recurring events for your purposes then you can just filter them out when you're looping through the results of the API call. I don't think there's any option you can set in the API request which would filter them out at source.

(I assume you're calling the https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list endpoint here btw, although you didn't actually say so in the question - feel free to [edit] it to make the post clearer).

@Adyson yes, via the Google Api Client

SOLVED:  Apparently, one particular Calendar was marked with a location tag (Office). Once I removed it, the API is NOW pulling only the active events!  Still, that does not make sense to me just yet, but it's working now. Sheeesh!
Thank you everyone for your thoughts. They do help!
